# Are 'how does one become an X' questions on topic?

Tags: discussion, on-topic-definition, asking-questions

I have often wondered how one joins a profession with a non-traditional career path.  Some examples are:

- How does one become a ship captain for an international freight line?
- What is a typical career path for becoming an astronaut?
- What is the career track for an overseas commercial pilot?

Would questions such as these be on-topic?  If not, is there another stack at which they might be?

Answer (score 5):

No.

We have a close reason that specifically declares this off topic.

> Questions asking for advice on what to do are not practical answerable
>   questions (e.g. "what job should I take?", or "what skills should I
>   learn?")

This type of question is basically asking what skills should I learn.

Comment: I was under the impression that we close those question because of the "I" in "What should *I* learn." we cannot possibly guess what is best for another person. But "how to become an airline pilot" seems to be pretty straightforward, unlike unanswerables like "C# or Java".

Comment: @Nvoight - No general how do I become a ___ questions have been off topic since early in beta.

Answer (score 3):

> Would questions such as these be on-topic

Questions like this are very hard to answer in a Q/A format and not a discussion, for a few reasons:

- They are normally very specific to the asker's circumstances, life priorities, and background
- They are impossible to conclusively answer except in rare cases
- Most careers have people who come into them in all manner of backgrounds. Nearly no job title/type has a one size fits all background and path to it

Each combination of interests and backgrounds will result in a customized answer to "how do I become an X?" which is very difficult to make useable for others.

These sorts of questions are much better for chat/forums where there will be large amounts of clarifying questions and responses.

The site [chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler) is a good place on the SE network.